# "aim life with money"

Tags: slang, syntactic-analysis, phrase-meaning

I am planning for a tattoo with image of target logo. and the caption I thought is "**Aim life with money**" Money being an arrow and the life being the "center of target".

I wanna make a point as in.. "live life fullest and is only possible with money so focus on your career" Blah blah...

**My question is am I getting it (the caption) right?**

Well.. firstly I am not asking for tattoo advice.. ***I am comparing my caption with my intention.***

Secondly.. I am 25. worked for 2 years.. and jobless since 1year.. and so missing all my outings, parties and FUN, unable to do whatever I want to, completely loaded up with responsibilities blah blah... Now trying to focus on something so that I can get back to my normal life but couldn't focus straight.

I believe the sole purpose of life is on three cap letters **F-U-N** well I am missing it now just because of the above reasons.

Comment: It's perfect... if you're wanting a good conversation starter. Otherwise, you might want to tweak the wording some. You may also want to aim questions with [ell.SE].

Comment: I can't imagine what saying you're trying to evoke, but this really isn't the place to ask for tattoo advice.  If your question is whether or not it's a gramatically correct sentence, I would say not, or at least it sounds very awkward.  What it sounds like you are saying is "I direct my life with my money", but I don't think that's what you are trying to say.

Comment: I am not sure how to word this, as it seems very strange. My tuppence-orth, and this is only my opinion, the basic premise is misguided; as you get older you will realise that living life to the full may have no connection to money; this will be a tattoo you will regret. If you do want it, I would avoid the caption and just leave the image you describe - it makes much more sense alone.

Comment: Seriously? Living life to the fullest involves focusing on your career? I really, really hope you are very young and will grow out of that. Maybe [this](http://zenpencils.com/comic/128-bill-watterson-a-cartoonists-advice/) will help.

Comment: Perhaps you should just tattoo a picture of the money on the bridge of your hand. That way each time you see your hand, you will remember to focus on money. In all seriousness, thank you for checking with internet friends before getting a tattoo. It's much better than not checking with internet friends before getting a tattoo.

Comment: Sticking to English usage here. One one can aim (*with*) a weapon or a projectile *for* or *towards* a target. One can also aim a weapon *with* an aiming aid (a scope or an iron sight). *Aim for life with money* probably means what you want, more or less. (Back to general life advise: I would strongly discourage getting such a tattoo, on various grounds).

Comment: Go to college.  You'll get a much better, higher paying job with a degree.  More money more fun.

Comment: Anyway, whether we agree with your position or not, this site is not the right place to ask. Either because it is too basic and any native speaker would know the answer (please read our [about] page to understand who this site is aimed at, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) would be a better choice for this question) or because proof reading questions, asking "Is this sentence correct" are specifically [off topic](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: However, dissecting the *meaning* of the OP's phrase can be a legitimate topic, though one that's probably erring on the side of opinion. FWIW - Jimmy Buffett's song says it best with his song, "A Permanent Reminder of a Temporary Feeling".  :-)

Comment: Philosophies change, but tats are eternal. A caption that would have a longer shelf life than your love life (there's nothing sadder than a tat with the name of an ex) might be "My Aim is True."

Answer (score 3):

If you're doing this for English speakers, then you probably want to be pithy and use Latin instead.  The kind of *material existentialism* you seek to denote is associated, by Westerners, with the Romans.

Something like :

> Semper Vitae Opes

Please do not trust my translation of Latin.

Comment: It is? I associate it much more with American or modern western society in general. Romans bring to mind orgies and abandon (mistakenly of course but that's the association).

Comment: +1 until Latin Tattoo Slogans gets out of beta, at which point I vote to migrate this question/answer.

Comment: @terdon what is more existentialist than an orgy? ;)

Comment: I think you mean sexistentialist. :)

Comment: Maybe it is a derivative...

Answer (score 1):

It does sound a bit awkward and might give one the impression that you're not a native English speaker.  If you add "at" between "aim" and "life," you conserve your meaning while removing the awkwardness.

"Aim ***at*** life with money"

Comment: This is an improvement, since it changes a non-grammatical sentence into a grammatical one; yet I still find it absurd and nonsensical, no matter how hard I try and wrap my brain around the metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

"Aim **at** life with money", might take out the ambiguity out of your caption,which right now sounds a little awkward and may not be understood without you explaining the context.

You could also use something to the effect of "When life is the target, money always hits Bull's Eye."

Answer (score 0):

There's always the wisdom from the motorcycle safety course that can be applied:

> **"You will hit what you aim at"**

And then there's the other pithy saying,

> **"Aim high.  Even if you miss, you'll land among the stars"**

Comment: The U.S. Air Force once ran a recruiting campaign with the slogan _Aim High_. That got superseded by another effort with the slogan _No One Comes Close_. That latter slogan got people chuckling; it could be paraphrased to "Everyone misses their target by a long way," with a follow-on thought by many, "Maybe they should aim at their target, instead of aiming high." I guess there is always an inherent danger that a concise four- or five-word slogan will be misinterpreted, be it intentionally or unintentionally.

Comment: @J.R., all the more reason to think *very carefully* before committing it to a tattoo! :-)